# DVI-D to Thunderbolt 2 to Thunderbolt 3

Tags: thunderbolt, dvi

I was previously using a thunderbolt 2 to DVI-D connection to successfully connect my macbook pro retina 2014 to my monitor as follows...

[image]

This works fine but I recently wanted to use the same monitor with my Macbook Pro 2017 and so bought [this thunderbolt 2 to 3 adapter](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MMEL2AM/A/thunderbolt-3-usb-c-to-thunderbolt-2-adapter) to give the following...

[image]

With this setup however I get no signal whatsoever at the Monitor and so am assuming I'm doing something stupid.  Any thoughts what the problem is would be appreciated, particularly any recommendations on a better way to go from thunderbolt 3 to DVI-D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hooking up multiple adapters in series to get from one type of connector to another, VIA a third type of adapter doesn't always work. However there are enough exceptions to the rule that it is worth trying if you don't mind losing money on unusable adapters or returning said adapters.

There are USB-C to DVI adapters that should work. Amazon sells several makes and models but a simple Google search should turn up a bunch more.

Comment: It’s important to note that Apple themselves recommend this adapter for specifically this purpose as Thunderbolt 3 is fully backward compatible with TB 1 & 2.

Answer (score 0):

Try this - [https://www.amazon.com/Paheven-Display-JellyFish-Mini-DisplayPort-Charging/dp/B079CBNK8M/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B079CBNK8M)

Personally I used to use a dual-link DVI (from olden days of 2013 Apple Cinema Display) to mini-DisplayPort adapter purchased from Apple to connect it to my MacBook Air. When I got the new MacBook Pro with TB3, I looked long and hard, and the aforementioned solution works for me in a converter daisy-chain. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

### USB-C to DVI Cable:

There are USB-C3.x/USB4/Thunderbolt-3 to DVI Cables:

- https://geizhals.eu/?cat=kabelhdm1&xf=8254_DVI&hloc=eu&sort=p
- https://www.google.com/search?q=dvi+dual+link+usb+c+Thunderbolt+cable+gold&tbm=shop

### Recommendation: Dual-link

I would recommend to buy a **dual-link** DVI-Cable, that is capable of (a)[1920×1080@144Hz](https://thetechnologyland.com/the-best-dvi-cable-for-144hz/) (b) [2560×1600@60Hz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface#Specifications) (c) [3840×2400@30Hz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface#Specifications).

### Alternatives: (a) HDMI to DVI or  (b) DP to DVI

However If you would have a DisplayPort/miniDisplayPort or HDMI/miniHDMI-Port I would recommend to use one of those, since USB-C/TB3 can sometimes be buggy.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is using a Thunderbolt adapter when you need a DisplayPort adapter.

DisplayPort and Thunderbolt use the same connectors but they are not the same kind of signal, kind of like how RCA jacks are used for line level audio and composite video when the signals are quite different.  The description for the Apple Thunderbolt 2 to 3 adapter on the Apple store website even says this adapter does not support DisplayPort video.

I don't see an Apple adapter for USB-C/DisplPort to DVI-D but there is an adapter for USB-C/DisplyPort to HDMI.  https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MUF82AM/A/usb-c-digital-av-multiport-adapter

The adapter doesn't have a DVI-D port but passive adapter cables to HDMI are inexpensive and available from a number of reputable dealers.  DVI-D and HDMI are in many ways the same thing with a different connector.

There's many ways to solve this problem.  One thing to look out for is passive DisplayPort to HDMI or DVI-D adapters, they only work on DisplayPort ports with HDMI/DVI backward compatibility built in, which Apple may not support.  Active adapters work on all DisplayPort ports, and often support higher resolutions but they cost more.  If your display has only DVI-D then the higher resolutions may not concern you as DVI-D is more limited than HDMI or DisplayPort.

Given the age of DVI there's not likely to be a solution available that doesn't stack two adapters together.  The safest path is likely a USB-C to HDMI dock or adapter, and then a passive HDMI to DVI cable.